# An example of a process which is markovian but it is not strongly markovian

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, markov-process

I need to show that the following process is markovian but not strongly markovian.

> Consider the following process $(X_{t})_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}$, starting from
>   position $x$
>
> 1. if $x = 0$ then $X_t=0$ for all times.
> 2. if $x \not = 0$ then $X$ is a standard Brownian motion, say $W_{t}$ starting from $x$.

I need to show that this process is markovian but not strongly markovian.

Firstly, I know that the transition function of $(X_{t})$ is given by

$$p_{t}f(x)= \left \lbrace \begin{array}{cc}  b_{t}f(x), & \text{ if } x \neq 0\\
f(0), & \text{ if } x=0 \end{array} \right. $$

where $b_{t}$ is the transition function of the brownian motion $W_{t}$.

And I am stuck in proving the markovianity, i.e. I don't know how to prove that, for any $B$ a Borel set we have that
$$E[\mathbb{1}_{B}(X_{t+s})|\mathcal{F}_{s}]=E[\mathbb{1}_{B}(X_{t+s})|X_{s}]$$

If anyone could help me with this I would be very thankful.

Comment: Hi Irene. Can you explain George's answer to me? Is this happening in $\mathbb{R}$? Is he saying that once the Brownian motion hits $0$, it stays $0$ forever? Or is he just choosing a random starting point and then doing Brownian motion forever?

Comment: @mathworker21 I think now my question is more clear.

Comment: Isn't Markov property that $E[1_B(X_{t+s}) | F_s] = E[1_B(X_{t+s}) | X_s]$?

Comment: Yes, it is. But, how to prove it?

Comment: ok, edit your question then.....

Comment: Sorry about that. Now it is correct.

Comment: I mean, doesn't that equality just follow from very basis properties about Brownian motion, that where you go depends just on where you currently are and not how you got there (i.e. markov)? I can try to look at the definition of brownian motion to get a rigorous argument, but it seems the equation you want is a very basic property of brownian motion. or am i missing something?

Comment: Probably you are right, but I don't know how to write it formally. I don't know how to arrive to the equality for $W_{t}$, which of course holds since it is a brownian motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider separately the case $x=0$ and $x \neq 0$.

> Case 1: Starting point $x=0$

If $x=0$, then $X_t=0$ for all $t \geq 0$, and so

$$\mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{E}(1_B(0) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = 1_B(0)$$ for all $s,t \geq 0$. Exactly the same reasoning gives

$$\mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid X_s) = \mathbb{E}(1_B(0) \mid X_s) = 1_B(0).$$ Hence, $$\mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid X_s).$$

> Case 2: Starting point $x \neq 0$

If $x \neq 0$, then $X_t=x+W_t$ for some Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ started at $0$. Note that the canonical filtration of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is the canonical filtration of $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$, i.e. there is no need to distinguish between the two filtrations. By the Markov property of Brownian motion, we have

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) &= \mathbb{E}(1_B(x+W_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = g(W_s) \end{align*} for $$g(y) := \mathbb{E}(1_B(x+y+W_t)).$$

Equivalently,

$$\mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = g(W_s+x-x) = g(X_s-x).\tag{1}$$

Since the right-hand side is $\sigma(X_s)$-measurable, it follows from the tower property of conditional expectation that

\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid X_s) &= \mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) \mid X_s \big] \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \mathbb{E}(g(X_s-x) \mid X_s) = g(X_s-x). \tag{2} \end{align*}

Hence,

$$\mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) \stackrel{(1)}{=} g(X_s-x) \stackrel{(2)}{=} \mathbb{E}(1_B(X_{t+s}) \mid X_s). $$